# how to get next and previous week date in android

Tags: android

```
public  String getCurrentWeekDate() {
    Calendar c = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println("Current week = " + Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
    System.out.println("Current week = " + Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
    String startDate = "", endDate = "";
    startDate = df.format(c.getTime());
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 6);
    endDate = df.format(c.getTime());
    System.out.println("Start Date = " + startDate);
    System.out.println("End Date = " + endDate);

    return  "";
}
```

this is my  code from which I am getting current week date in given time format like  2017-07-17 to 2017-07-23 .

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.previousButtonView) {
     getCurrentWeekDate();
} else if (v.getId() == R.id.nextButtonView) {
     getCurrentWeekDate();
}
```

this is my code from which I have to display next week and previous week date please suggest me how to increase and decrease week date i am new in android.

Answer (score 1):

For next week `calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);`

For previous week `calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, -1);`

```
public void getCurrentWeekDate(int week) {
    Calendar c = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    c.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, c.getFirstDayOfWeek());
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, week);
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
    String startDate;
    String endDate;
    startDate = df.format(c.getTime());
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 6);
    endDate = df.format(c.getTime());
    System.out.println("Start Date = " + startDate);
    System.out.println("End Date = " + endDate);
}
```

Comment: getCurrentWeekDate(1);  for next and  getCurrentWeekDate(-1); for previous is it ?

Comment: but i have to maintain suppose that if click on previous then it should display previous again we click on previous button then previous to previous week like that if click next then previous to previous week to previous week and then again we click on next week then it should display current week .

Comment: Check my answer again. I made the method accept week as parameter. Basically if you call `getCurrentWeekDate(0)` it indicates this week, `getCurrentWeekDate(1)` next week, `getCurrentWeekDate(-1)` previous week.

Comment: Can you accept the answer if this is working for you?

Comment: no actually its not working look i have done like this https://paste.ofcode.org/vUuxDP5fY7Z6bSqmPM2C4q  current week 2017-07-17 - 2017-07-17 and if click on next then it should display 2017-07-24 -2017 -2017-07-30 if we click on previous then it should 2017-07-17 - 2017-07-17 and again if click previous then it should 2017-07-10 -2017-07-6 like this i want but ur code give only one day differnce

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149562/discussion-between-adevelopment-and-santalu).

Answer (score 1):

If you want the previous week **start** and **end** date, decrement *currentWeekNumber* by 1

else if you want next week **start** and **end** date increment *currentWeekNumber* by 1

```
    //initialize Calendar
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    
    //get current week number
    int currentWeekNumber = c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
    
    //decrement week number by 1 for the previous week
    c.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, currentWeekNumber - 1);

    //increment week number by 1 for the next week
    //c.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, currentWeekNumber + 1);        

    //set first day of week
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);
    
    //get start date of previous week
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
    String startDate = df.format(c.getTime());
    
    //set last day of week
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 7);
    
    //get end date of previous week
    String endDate = df.format(c.getTime());

    Log.d("LOG_TAG", "Start Date = " + startDate);
    Log.d("LOG_TAG", "End Date = " + endDate);
```

Comment: thanks working great! btw according to above code start day of week is Sunday and end day of week is Saturday

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already found current week's date, all you have to do is subtract 7 days for previous week dates and add 7 days for next week date.

You can do that by following code

```
int x = -7;
Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
cal.add( Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, x);
Date sevenDaysAgo = cal.getTime();
```

So your code will look like below -

```
 public void getCurrentWeekDate(int week) {
    Calendar c = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println("Current week = " + Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
    System.out.println("Current week = " + Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
    String startDate;
    String endDate;
    startDate = df.format(c.getTime());

    // previous week calculation
    Calendar previousWeekCalendar = c;
    previousWeekCalendar.add( Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -7);
    startPreviousWeekDate = df.format(previousWeekCalendar.getTime());
    previousWeekCalendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 6);
    endPreviousWeekDate = df.format(previousWeekCalendar.getTime());

    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 6);
    //for previous week
    //c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, -1);
    //for next week
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, week);
    endDate = df.format(c.getTime());


    // Do next week calculation same as previous week. Just check what is the value of c before starting the calculation
    System.out.println("Start Date = " + startDate);
    System.out.println("End Date = " + endDate);
    System.out.println("End Date = " + endDate);

}
```

Comment: i=6;
        if (v.getId() == R.id.previousButtonView) {
            i=i+6;

            getCurrentWeekDate(i);
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.nextButtonView)

        {
           i=i-6;
            getCurrentWeekDate(i);
        }   its not working dear

Comment: each time its give current date

Comment: What is the issue coming. Please add your modified code for me to debug :)

Comment: I have added the calculation for previous week in the updated code in the answer. similarly you can do for next week.

Comment: Calendar previousWeekCalendar = c.add( Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -7);  Error is coming also startPreviousWeekDate and endPreviousWeekDate not defiend

Comment: Updated as that line was not needed and most computations were at top. Also of course you would have to define them at the same place and in same way as endDate.

Answer (score 0):

So many tries I got this result:

```
fun getWeekDates(currentWeek: Int): Array<String?> {
   val daysOfWeek = arrayOfNulls<String>(7)
   val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
   calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY)
   calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, currentWeek)
   for (i in 0..6) {
      daysOfWeek[i] = changeDateFormat(LocalDate(calendar.time))
      calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
  }
  return daysOfWeek
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
fun getLastWeekRange(): String {
    val calendarFrom = Calendar.getInstance()
    val calendarTo = Calendar.getInstance()
    val dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
    val fotmat = SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy")
    if (dayOfWeek == 1) {
        calendarFrom.add(Calendar.DATE, -(dayOfWeek + 12))
        calendarTo.add(Calendar.DATE, -(dayOfWeek + 6))
    } else {
        calendarFrom.add(Calendar.DATE, -(dayOfWeek + 5))
        calendarTo.add(Calendar.DATE, -(dayOfWeek - 1))
    }

    return "[${fotmat.format(calendarFrom.time)} - ${fotmat.format(calendarTo.time)}]"
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).